# Tableau SQL query: Oracle database error 907: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, tableau-api

Trying to copy some SQL into Tableau's SQL Query to pull from some tables. However, getting the error mentioned in the title. Can anyone tell what is wrong with my query? I am using Oracle SQL. Thank you!

Note: Sensitive info has been replaced with various letters.

```
WITH TBL AS (SELECT    g.reg_key,
          d.rpt_yr       AS sold_year,
          d.rpt_wk_of_yr AS sold_week,
          u.cd,
          u.cur_nm,
          CASE
                    WHEN p.app_desc IN ('r', 's') THEN 'on'
                    WHEN v.location_type IN ('x', 'y', 'z') THEN 'off'
                    ELSE 'on'
          END AS on_off,
          CASE
                    WHEN s.name = 'EX' THEN 'Ex'
                    ELSE p.app_desc
          END AS txn_application,
          Max_by(e.new_old ||'#' ||e.a_flag ||'#' ||e.TYPE, e.purchase_dt) AS prior_experian
FROM      tableau.fact_registration g
join      tableau.dim u
ON        u.KEY = g.KEY
AND       Trim(Upper(u.company_type_nm)) = 'TIM'
AND       Trim(Upper(u.country_cd)) = 'US'
join      tableau.dim_account c
ON        c.acct_key = g.owner_acct_key
AND       Trim(Upper(c.mkt_segment_cat)) = 'NAME'
join      tableau.dim_date d
ON        d.dt_key = g.dt_key
AND       d.rpt_yr >= 2018
AND       d.rpt_wk <
          (
                 SELECT rpt_wk
                 FROM   tableau.dim_date
                 WHERE  full_dt = Trunc(SYSDATE) limit 1)
join      tableau.TYPE m
ON        m.type_key = g.type_key
join      tableau.dim_application p
ON        p.app_key = g.txn_app_key
AND       p.app_desc IN ('q', 'r', 's')
left join tableau.dim_digital_datasource s
ON        s.digital_datasource_key = g.digital_datasource_key
left join tableau.location v
ON        v.location_key = g.location_key
left join dsrep.fav e
ON        e.no_chk_cd = substr(trim(upper(g.no)), 9, 1)
AND       e.year*10000+e.month*100 < g.check_in_dt_key
AND       trim(upper(e.no)) = trim(upper(g.no))
GROUP BY  1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
SELECT   sold_year,
         sold_week,
         cd,
         cur_nm,
         txn_application,
         on_off,
         CASE
                  WHEN prior_experian IN ('XYZ') THEN 'off'
                  ELSE 'not off'
         END      AS was_new,
         count(*) AS n_sold
FROM     tbl
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7;
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle Database or MySQL? `LIMIT 1` is not valid Oracle SQL - you would use `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` instead.

Comment: Oracle does not support`group by` by column's ordinal position or alias, only by column name or expression.

Comment: @kfinity Thank you! I believe the source was MySQL, so it seems I need to go about changing some of the syntax for Oracle. Thank you for pointing this out